# How to format a Xml-Stream for writing into file

Tags: xml, stream

I request a very large (>500mb) xml file from a web-service and write the contents of the `ResponseStream` directly into a `FileStream`. But when i open the resulting xml-file the contents look like this:

```
<Changes requestChangeTrackingId="-1" resultChangeTrackingId="2387">
<Selectors>
<Selector selectorId="1"><DateValidFrom>2000-01-01T00:00:00</DateValidFrom><DateValidTo>2099-12-31T00:00:00</DateValidTo><Code20Z>01A</Code20Z><CodeNUM/><CodeENT>1</CodeENT><ShortName>01A</ShortName></Selector>
<Selector selectorId="2"><DateValidFrom>2000-01-01T00:00:00</DateValidFrom><DateValidTo>2099-12-31T00:00:00</DateValidTo><Code20Z>01B</Code20Z><CodeNUM/><CodeENT>2</CodeENT><ShortName>01B</ShortName></Selector>
```

How can i format the stream so that it will look like this:

```
<Changes requestChangeTrackingId="-1" resultChangeTrackingId="2387">
<Selectors>
<Selector selectorId="1">
   <DateValidFrom>2000-01-01T00:00:00</DateValidFrom>
   <DateValidTo>2099-12-31T00:00:00</DateValidTo>
   <Code20Z>01A</Code20Z>
   <CodeNUM/>
   <CodeENT>1</CodeENT>
   <ShortName>01A</ShortName>
</Selector>
[...]
```

I cannot load the whole file into memory and therefore can't use a solution like

```
XDocument.Load( responseStream ).Save( "somefile.xml" );
```

Is there a way to pass a stream into some kind of XmlStreamFormatter and write the stream directly into the filesystem? The files to store can be so big that its not possible to always load the whole stream into memory and format it there.

Comment: Either you'll need to create enough of an XML parser to perform formatting (this would be a bad idea). Or you'll need to parse the XML (eg. via an `XmlReader`) enough to feed into an minimal XSLT transforming that includes `indent="yes"` in an `<xsl:output>` element. (A third option would be a custom `XmlWriter` to do it... not as hard as the first option but harder than the XSLT if you know XSTL. NB. any option that involves a complete 500MB XML file into memory better have plenty of memory to run in!

Comment: Additional: why do you want it formatting. 500MB XML is too big to process manually in any useful fashion.

Comment: @Richard i just want to format it because it will provide better readability for someone who need to verify what kind of data was send via the webservice. For automated processing there is no need to do it.

Comment: It turns out that I had forgotten about `XmlWriterSettings.Indent`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`XmlWriterSettings.Indent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.indent) provides the core of a mechanism here, so it a matter of ensuring that the whole content does not need to be loaded (but some careful testing with performance counters running is definitely advisable. Just one component too eager to read data in could lead to large address space and commit usage. Therefore with data sizes of the order of 500MB I would ensure this is built for x64 only—no AnyCPU builds.

So something like:

```
void FormatXmlToFile(FileStream input, string outputFile) {
    using (var output = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.CreateNew)) {
        var reader = XmlReader.Create(input);
        var writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings {
            Indent = true
        };

        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(output, writerSettings)) {
            writer.WriteNode(reader, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to run this on a UI thread, then replace [`WriteNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/1wd6aw1b) with [`WriteNodeAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh141308), convert to an `async` method and update UI for completed when the returned `Task` completes.