# How to parse large XML file from a stream?

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net

I have the following code:

```vb
// load a über big xml file from a stream
Dim xmldoc As New XmlDocument
xmldoc.Load(logStream)

// squeeze it into the StringBuilder instance
Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
Using tw As New StringWriter(sb)
  Using xtw As New Xml.XmlTextWriter(tw)
    xtw.Formatting = Xml.Formatting.Indented
    xmldoc.WriteTo(xtw)
  End Using
End Using

// then write it to the file
Using fs = New FileStream(m_filename, If(logged, FileMode.Append, FileMode.Create), FileAccess.Write)
  Using sw As New StreamWriter(fs)
    sw.Write(sb.ToString())
  End Using
End Using
```

The problem is that logStream is SO BIG that running this code blows up the entire building.

I need to find a way to parse it line by line or in chunks or whatever. Anything that does not. I want to use XmlDocument because it allows me to apply indentation.

How can it be done?

Comment: Use `XmlReader` instead of `XmlDocument`. The reader allows you to stream through the data instead of loading it all in to memory at once.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a Xml-Stream for writing into file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18589813/how-to-format-a-xml-stream-for-writing-into-file)